# Can I travel from USA to India with OCI Card and US Passport expiring in 60 days

Tags: air-travel

Can I travel from USA to India with OCI Card and US Passport that is expiring in 60 days?

Comment: It's certainly permissible under US law, but I don't know about Indian law, and of the flight is not direct you will have to consider the rules in your country or countries of transit.  Is the flight direct?  If not, will you need to clear immigration controls while you are in transit?

Comment: Before you go you should consider how are you going to renew your passport. Issuance is taking several months if you applied in the US. You should expect it to take even longer if you apply from India.